# make file fails with unknown type error?

Tags: c

I am attempting to run a make file for a [third party piece of software](https://pjreddie.com/darknet/yolo/) but I am getting an error when I run it:

```
$ make
gcc -Iinclude/ -Isrc/ -Wall -Wfatal-errors  -Ofast -c ./src/gemm.c -o obj/gemm.o
In file included from ./src/gemm.c:2:
In file included from src/utils.h:5:
In file included from src/list.h:3:
include/darknet.h:491:1: fatal error: unknown type name 'pthread_t'
pthread_t load_data(load_args args);
^
1 error generated.
make: *** [obj/gemm.o] Error 1
```

I'm not very familiar with C, but from what I can tell `pthread_t` is a datatype that is similar to an int.  I looked at the line that is causing the error:

```
pthread_t load_data(load_args args);
```

but don't see anything that would be an obvious cause of the problem.

I looked in my make file and I see this line:

```
LDFLAGS= -lm -pthread
```

Could this be part of the problem?

Does anyone know what I might need to do in order to get the `pthread_t` type recognized so I can run the make file?

I apologize if the answer is obvious - I tried googling the specific error message I was getting but didn't turn much up.  Please let me know if I need to post any other other code than what I have already included.

Comment: That type comes from `#include <pthread.h>`. Either the source is missing that or your system does not have the pthread headers installed.

Comment: Grep your src for `pthread_t` and see which header defines it - then include that in your gemm.c or an appropriate header already included

Comment: That's not a makefile problem.

Comment: The wording of your question is inconsistent with the solution you marked as "accepted". The problem you described (specifically, "unknown type name" error), cannot be fixed that way. It clearly indicates that your `#include` structure does not include `<pthread.h>` before trying to refer to `pthread_t` type. Solving it would require adding an `#include` directive in the source code, not manipulating some command-line options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error comes from not including the pthread library (assuming you are compiling this for a posix compliant system, if you are on windows pthreads are unlikely to work).

See were the pthread library is installed in your machine and include it in the command line.

Comment: Yep - that was it.  I'm sure that was an obvious answer to someone with C experience - thanks for the help.

Comment: ??? Um.. How can it possibly be a correct answer? What "command line" is this answer referring to? The error message clearly indicates a missing `#include` directive in one of the source files. "Command line" has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Lol command line refers to the shell, like gcc <flags> source.c And all he was missing is the path to the header file in the include

Comment: @Makogan: Nope. If he was missing the path, the error message would be completely different. In that case it would state that `#include` directive refers to a header file that cannot be found. But the message quoted by the OP indicates a completely different error: missing `#include` directive.

Comment: Also if they poster flagged it as the answer and they thanked me I think I solved their issue

Comment: @Makogan: That's why I posted my comment: if this "solution" indeed "resolved" the issue, it means that the either the original question is broken (described the problem in misleading or completely incorrect way), or that the flagging was made gratuitously.

Comment: @AnT that's not true, it depends on where the compiler first finds an error.  If the compiler first tries to compile a file that uses a pthread inside of an extern declared function or something like that it will report the type before  the header. My answer solved OP's problem so I suspect I am correct in the solution I gave.

Comment: @Makogan: But that's exactly my point. If such arrangement exists in the OP's source code, it will not be fixed by adding a command line flag with path to headers. The error quoted by the OP has absolutely nothing to do with any paths. It clearly shows that no attempt was made to `#include` the header. If the header is not `#include`d explicitly, no amount of command line options will make the compiler to do it for the OP.

Comment: I've gotten errors like this before when compiling my own source code (which contained no external libraries) and a lot of the time the compiler complained about undefined types before complaining about headers.

Comment: @Makogan: Once again, that's exactly my point. If compiler complains about undefined third-party type, it means that no attempt was made to `#include` the proper header. Adding command-line options will not magically include that header. Adding command-line options will not fix anything in such cases. You have to go into your source code and `#include` the proper header in the proper spot. (After that you can start worrying about supplying the proper paths in the command line, if necessary.) The OP's error message clearly indicates a missing `#include <pthread.h>` in the source code.

Comment: That problem happens when the header file (which is at the end nothing but a huge macro) cannot be found, as the compiler fails to find structure or functions declarations that are needed for the linking step. This usually happens because the header is in a directory that is not found in the include path the compiler uses to search for included headers.

Comment: @Makogan: When a header specified in an `#include` directive cannot be found, if immediately triggers an error message stating exactly that and immediately terminates the translation of that translation unit. There's no compiler in existence that would glide over an `#include` directive with not-found header and then just complain about "unknown types". It does not work that way in C implementations. The OP seems to be using GCC. GCC does not quietly skip over `#include` directives with not-found headers.

Comment: I feel we are just spamming this, considering this post is probably going to get lost into oblivion and that the problem seems fixed, I suggest we drop the subject.